# Exporting complex HTML table to Excel

Tags: javascript, html, xml, excel, html-table

I want to export an `HTML` table to excel sheet.
I would have done this with CVS format if I didn't have to keep some formatting and add pictures.

I have tries using the `Office 2003 XML` format for that, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
          xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
          xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
          xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
          xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    ...
    </DocumentProperties>
    <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    ...
    </OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
    ...
    </ExcelWorkbook>
    <Styles>...</Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">...</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

And then some `JavaScript` code to "download" it using `data URI` and

```
'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8, '+
 encodeURIComponent(STRING_XML_REPRESENTATION));
```

I have 2 problems:

1. The document saved as `xls` (or `xlsx`) opens fine on `OpeOffice` \ `LibreOffice` but throws an error on `Excel`, and
2. I do not seem to find a way to add images to the file.

I do not want to save it as an `xml` file since opening it defaults to a web browser in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review ECMA-376.  Excel expects all of the files to be included in a zip container (and you must have a few additional files, including `[Content_Types].xml`)

Images must be added to the zip container and referenced (review the spec).

Comment: How can I do this programatically?